# List of oEmbed providers

Tags: oembed

I am trying to find out all the oEmbed providers out there. I went to the oEmbed spec site and they have a few, but I found out a few other that weren't specified, like 5min video:

```
Provider: 5min
URL scheme: http://www.5min.com/video/*
API Endpoint: http://api.5min.com/oembed.{format}
Docs: http://www.5min.com/APIDocs/Embed.aspx
```

Nothing better than to ask the developer community in StackOverflow.

Comment: Note that 5min uses max_width and max_height instead of the standard maxwidth and maxheight params.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Embedly looks to have a good collection: http://api.embed.ly/

Answer (score 6):

The oohembed.com domain was recently aquired by Embed.ly, but the code is still open source, and the endpoints json can still be found here: http://code.google.com/p/oohembed/source/browse/app/provider/endpoints.json

Comment: RIP, the above link. Here's a link to at file, exported to github: https://github.com/stetelepta/oohembed/blob/master/app/provider/endpoints.json

Answer (score 5):

It seems like embed.ly does no longer provide a public list of oembed providers. Therefore I'm currently in the process of compiling my own: https://github.com/panzi/OembedEndpoints I added some providers already, but next I'll look through the services supported by embed.ly and add all that actually have a oembed endpoint (and aren't just wrapped by embed.ly).

Comment: This is a good list (better than oohembed), but has not been updated since 2013.

Comment: [There has](https://github.com/panzi/oembedendpoints/commits/master) since then been a minor update.

Answer (score 5):

http://noembed.com/providers

```
[{
    "patterns": ["http://(?:www\\.)?xkcd\\.com/\\d+/?"],
    "name": "XKCD"
}, {
    "patterns": ["https?://soundcloud.com/.*/.*"],
    "name": "SoundCloud"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://(?:www\\.)?flickr\\.com/.*"],
    "name": "Flickr"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://www\\.ted\\.com/talks/.+\\.html"],
    "name": "TED"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://(?:www\\.)?theverge\\.com/\\d{4}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d+/[^/]+/?$"],
    "name": "The Verge"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://.*\\.viddler\\.com/.*"],
    "name": "Viddler"
}, {
    "patterns": ["https?://(?:www\\.)?wired\\.com/[^/]+/\\d+/\\d+/[^/]+/?$"],
    "name": "Wired"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://www\\.theonion\\.com/articles/[^/]+/?"],
    "name": "The Onion"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://yfrog\\.com/[0-9a-zA-Z]+/?$"],
    "name": "YFrog"
}, {
    "patterns": ["https?://(?:www.)?skitch.com/([^/]+)/[^/]+/.+", "http://skit.ch/[^/]+"],
    "name": "Skitch"
}, {
    "patterns": ["https?://(alpha|posts|photos)\\.app\\.net/.*"],
    "name": "ADN"
}, {
    "patterns": ["https?://gist\\.github\\.com/(?:[-0-9a-zA-Z]+/)?([0-9a-fA-f]+)"],
    "name": "Gist"
}, {
    "patterns": ["https?://www\\.(dropbox\\.com/s/.+\\.(?:jpg|png|gif))", "https?://db\\.tt/[a-zA-Z0-9]+"],
    "name": "Dropbox"
}, {
    "patterns": ["https?://[^\\.]+\\.wikipedia\\.org/wiki/(?!Talk:)[^#]+(?:#(.+))?"],
    "name": "Wikipedia"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://www.traileraddict.com/trailer/[^/]+/trailer"],
    "name": "TrailerAddict"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://lockerz\\.com/[sd]/\\d+"],
    "name": "Lockerz"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://trailers\\.apple\\.com/trailers/[^/]+/[^/]+"],
    "name": "iTunes Movie Trailers"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://bash\\.org/\\?(\\d+)"],
    "name": "Bash.org"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://arstechnica\\.com/[^/]+/\\d+/\\d+/[^/]+/?$"],
    "name": "Ars Technica"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://imgur\\.com/gallery/[0-9a-zA-Z]+"],
    "name": "Imgur"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://www\\.asciiartfarts\\.com/[0-9]+\\.html"],
    "name": "ASCII Art Farts"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://www\\.monoprice\\.com/products/product\\.asp\\?.*p_id=\\d+"],
    "name": "Monoprice"
}, {
    "patterns": ["https?://(?:[^\\.]+\\.)?youtube\\.com/watch/?\\?(?:.+&)?v=([^&]+)", "https?://youtu\\.be/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)"],
    "name": "YouTube"
}, {
    "patterns": ["https?://github\\.com/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/commit/(.+)", "http://git\\.io/[_0-9a-zA-Z]+"],
    "name": "Github Commit"
}, {
    "patterns": ["https?://open\\.spotify\\.com/(track|album)/([0-9a-zA-Z]{22})"],
    "name": "Spotify"
}, {
    "patterns": ["https?://path\\.com/p/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$"],
    "name": "Path"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://www.funnyordie.com/videos/[^/]+/.+"],
    "name": "Funny or Die"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://(?:www\\.)?twitpic\\.com/([^/]+)"],
    "name": "Twitpic"
}, {
    "patterns": ["https?://www\\.giantbomb\\.com/videos/[^/]+/\\d+-\\d+/?"],
    "name": "GiantBomb"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://(?:www\\.)?beeradvocate\\.com/beer/profile/\\d+/\\d+"],
    "name": "Beer Advocate"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://(?:www\\.)?imdb.com/title/(tt\\d+)"],
    "name": "IMDB"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://cl\\.ly/(?:image/)?[0-9a-zA-Z]+/?$"],
    "name": "CloudApp"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://www\\.hulu\\.com/watch/.*"],
    "name": "Hulu"
}, {
    "patterns": ["https?://(?:www\\.)?twitter\\.com/(?:#!/)?[^/]+/status(?:es)?/(\\d+)/?$", "http://t\\.co/[a-zA-Z0-9]+"],
    "name": "Twitter"
}, {
    "patterns": ["https?://(?:www\\.)?vimeo\\.com/.+"],
    "name": "Vimeo"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://www\\.amazon\\.com/(?:.+/)?[gd]p/(?:product/)?(?:tags-on-product/)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)", "http://amzn\\.com/([^/]+)"],
    "name": "Amazon"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://qik\\.com/video/.*"],
    "name": "Qik"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://www\\.rdio\\.com/#/artist/[^/]+/album/[^/]+/?", "http://www\\.rdio\\.com/#/artist/[^/]+/album/[^/]+/track/[^/]+/?", "http://www\\.rdio\\.com/#/people/[^/]+/playlists/\\d+/[^/]+"],
    "name": "Rdio"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://www\\.slideshare\\.net/.*/.*"],
    "name": "SlideShare"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://imgur\\.com/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$"],
    "name": "Imgur"
}, {
    "patterns": ["https?://instagr(?:\\.am|am\\.com)/p/.+"],
    "name": "Instagram"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://www\\.twitlonger\\.com/show/[a-zA-Z0-9]+", "http://tl\\.gd/[^/]+"],
    "name": "Twitlonger"
}, {
    "patterns": ["https?://vine.co/v/[a-zA-Z0-9]+"],
    "name": "Vine"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://www\\.urbandictionary\\.com/define\\.php\\?term=.+"],
    "name": "Urban Dictionary"
}, {
    "patterns": ["http://picplz\\.com/user/[^/]+/pic/[^/]+"],
    "name": "Picplz"
}, {
    "patterns": ["https?://(?:www\\.)?twitter\\.com/(?:#!/)?[^/]+/status(?:es)?/(\\d+)/photo/\\d+(?:/large|/)?$", "https?://pic\\.twitter\\.com/.+"],
    "name": "Twitter"
}]
```

Comment: And how do you get provider specific oEmbed url from there?

Comment: They are open source and do include the provider URL in their code (so you could get it from there or use it to generate a list that includes the URL): https://github.com/leedo/noembed/blob/master/lib/Noembed/Provider

Answer (score 4):

Embed.ly wraps a lot of sites' APIs in the oEmbed standards. Not all of those sites support OEmbed.

Answer (score 4):

http://oembed.com lists some providers and provides a link to a more comprehensive list: http://oembed.com/providers.json

Answer (score 1):

This project is worth noting: https://github.com/itteco/iframely. It's modern, maintained and has a SaaS-hosted API option via https://iframely.com.

Answer (score 1):

**embedo** does that, its lightweight and easy api. You can try it for your case https://shobhitsharma.github.io/embedo